# How to properly design objects with internal references to disposable objects

Tags: c#, idisposable

Suppose, I have following classes:

```
public class DisposableObj : IDisposable
{
    public ChildObj CreateObj();
    internal object GetSomething();
    // ...
}

public class ChildObj
{
    private DisposableObj m_provider;

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        m_provider.GetSomething();
    }
    // ...
}
```

It's possible that at some point the disposable object will be disposed but child object will still have a reference to it.

If at this time user will call `DoSomething` method then child object will try to access disposed object. This is not good hence the question:

How should I properly design such classes?

UPDATE/CLARIFICATION:

I am aware of ObjectDisposedException and all. My question probably should sound like: how to properly notify user about exceptional situation and how design the classes to make maintaining them easier?

Comment: It is impossible to *not* have a reference to a disposed object.  You couldn't dispose it.  A properly implemented disposable class raises ObjectDisposedException, you do not have to help.

Comment: @HansPassant It's completely clear to me that child objects must has reference to parent object. The question is: how to properly notify user about exceptional situation and how design the classes to make maintaining them easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While that is a scenario that is technically possible, this should be an *exceptional* state in your progam - I can't imagine why you would deliberately set up for this scenario.

Having said, that make it clear in your design who is responsible to dispose `DisposableObj` and when - if any child accesses the disposed object afterwards you can argue that this *should* cause an exception - don't work around this but throw an exception an let the exception bubble up so you can fix the logic when you discover the problem.

Implementation-wise you can achieve this by just keeping a boolean that keeps track of whether `DisposableObj` is disposed and on a later access just throw `ObjectDisposedException`. To clarify I mean the `DisposableObj` object *itself* should keep track of its state and throw `ObjectDisposedException` on any method call on it after it was disposed.

Comment: Why keep track of it? Any method on the disposed object should throw the same exception too.

Comment: That's what I meant: `DisposableObj` should keep track of its state and throw `ObjectDisposedException`, maybe that sentence was not clearly stated

Comment: @BrokenGlass, Thank you, I clarified my question, though.

Comment: @Bobrovsky: Not sure what your update adds - the exception *is* the notification for consumers of the class.

Answer (score 2):

First thougth that comes to mind:
Provide your ChildObj class with an internal boolean property called ProviderDisposed.
Set this property to true from Dispose in your DisposableObj

However you should keep a list of the objects created to comunicate to each one the disposed state of your main object.

```
List<ChildObj> childsCreated = new List<ChildObj>();
public ChildObj CreateObj()
{
    ChildObj obj = new ChildObj();
    childsCreated.Add(obj);
    return obj;
}
public void Dispose()
{
    Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}

protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    // Check to see if Dispose has already been called.
    if(!this.disposed)
    {
        if(disposing)
        {
            foreach(ChildObj obj in childsCreated)
                obj.ProviderDisposed = true;
            childsCreated = null;
        }
        disposed = true;
    }
}

public class ChildObj   
{   
    private DisposableObj m_provider;   
    private bool m_providerDisposed = false;

    public bool ProviderDisposed 
    { set { m_providerDisposed = true; } }

    public void DoSomething()   
    {   
        if(m_providerDisposed == false)
             m_provider.GetSomething();
        // else // as from **@BrokenGlass answer**
        //     throw new ObjectDisposedException();   
    }   
    // ...   
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the example. But wouldn't such approach prevent garbage collector from properly collecting objects? After all, each child has reference to parent and parent has reference to each child.

Comment: No, I don't think so, When DisposableObject is disposed, its internal references to the ChildObject list will be removed.   Waiting to be denied.... However to be sure, adding a childsCreated = null; The ChildObject instead is as before.

Comment: You are right (I get this, after writing the comment). But while parent disposable is not disposed it must keep references to all created objects. And this will probably prevent created objects from being collected. But maybe weak references will help here.

Comment: The Garbage collector can deal with circular references. They are not a problem at all.

Comment: Yes, [WeakReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference.aspx) class seems the way to go...

Comment: @HenkHolterman Could you elaborate on your statement? I am really interested in this at the time.

Comment: @Bobrovsky - just google it. Some reading [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985010.aspx)